# Como copiar dados da coluna de uma tabela para outra tabela

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle, pl-sql

Possuo uma tabela chamada `UC` que possui uma coluna email, e tenho uma tabela de backup da mesma.

Preciso copiar os dados (emails) da coluna email da tabela `backup` para a coluna `email` da tabela `uc`, porém não sei como fazer isso.

Fiz varias tentativas, sem sucesso. Nunca havia me deparado com essa situação, copiar dados entre tabelas.

```
update uc 
set uc.email =  backup.email
from uc , backup
where uc.idconsumidor =  backup.idconsumidor;
```

Comment: O que é `onsumidor`?

Comment: desculpe , eu havia confundindo a tabela , já corrigi

Comment: Isto em teoria funciona. Você faz o commit das informações como? Por comando ou por algum botão do editor?

Comment: Então , eu não fiz o commit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Da pra fazer também com um for:

```
BEGIN
  FOR rec IN (SELECT bk.email
                    ,uc.id_consumidor
                FROM uc
                    ,backup bk
               WHERE uc.idconsumidor = bk.idconsumidor)
  LOOP
    UPDATE uc
       SET uc.email = rec.email
     WHERE uc.idconsumidor = rec.id_consumidor;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Na query do for já fiz o join entre as tabelas, então já garanto que só trará registros que realmente precisam ser alterados.
Dentro do loop faço o update.

Answer (score 6):

```
UPDATE uc u
   SET (email) = (SELECT b.email
                  FROM backup b
                  WHERE u.idconsumidor = b.idconsumidor)
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
      FROM backup b2
     WHERE u.idconsumidor = b2.idconsumidor)
```

O WHERE de fora (o 2º) existe para evitar que você atualize registros na tabela *u* que não possuam correspondentes na tabela *backup*. Sem esse where, registros sem correspondência teriam a coluna *email* setada pra NULL.

Answer (score 5):

O script para atualizar o e-mail a partir da tabela backup pode ser feito da seguinte forma:

```sql
/* AMBIENTE DE TESTE: Tabelas temporárias para testar o script */
create global temporary table tmp_uc
(   
    idconsumidor int,
    email varchar2(100)
)
on commit preserve rows;

create global temporary table tmp_backup
(   
    idconsumidor int,
    email varchar2(100)
)
on commit preserve rows;

--Dados para teste
insert into tmp_uc (idconsumidor, email) values (1, 'AAAAA@uc');
insert into tmp_uc (idconsumidor, email) values (2, 'BBBBB@uc');
insert into tmp_uc (idconsumidor, email) values (3, 'CCCCC@uc');
insert into tmp_uc (idconsumidor, email) values (4, 'DDDDD@uc');
insert into tmp_uc (idconsumidor, email) values (5, 'EEEEE@uc');
insert into tmp_uc (idconsumidor, email) values (6, 'FFFFF@uc');
insert into tmp_uc (idconsumidor, email) values (7, 'GGGGG@uc');
insert into tmp_uc (idconsumidor, email) values (8, 'HHHHH@uc');
insert into tmp_uc (idconsumidor, email) values (9, 'IIIII@uc');

insert into tmp_backup (idconsumidor, email) values (1, 'AAAAA@bkp');
insert into tmp_backup (idconsumidor, email) values (2, 'BBBBB@bkp');
insert into tmp_backup (idconsumidor, email) values (3, 'CCCCC@bkp');
insert into tmp_backup (idconsumidor, email) values (4, 'DDDDD@bkp');
insert into tmp_backup (idconsumidor, email) values (5, 'EEEEE@bkp');
insert into tmp_backup (idconsumidor, email) values (6, 'FFFFF@bkp');
insert into tmp_backup (idconsumidor, email) values (7, 'GGGGG@bkp');

/* Atualização dos e-mails na tabela temporária tmp_uc para fins de teste */
update 
(   select
            u.email as email_U,
            bk.email as email_BK
    from tmp_uc u
    inner join tmp_backup bk on u.idconsumidor = bk.idconsumidor
    --where (...)
) t
set t.email_U = t.email_BK

select * from tmp_uc;

commit;

/*
idconsumidor   email
    1          AAAAA@bkp
    2          BBBBB@bkp
    3          CCCCC@bkp
    4          DDDDD@bkp
    5          EEEEE@bkp
    6          FFFFF@bkp
    7          GGGGG@bkp
    8          HHHHH@uc
    9          IIIII@uc
*/
```

Se o script tiver funcionado da forma desejada, pode utilizar o seguinte script para as suas tabelas físicas:

```sql
-- Atualização dos dados na tabela física
    update 
    (   select
            u.email as email_U,
            bk.email as email_BK
        from UC u
        inner join backup bk on u.idconsumidor = bk.idconsumidor
        --where (...)
    ) t
    set t.email_U = t.email_BK

    commit;
```

Answer (score 4):

Acho que faltou o `COMMIT` ao final:

```
update uc 
set uc.email = backup.email
from backup
where uc.idconsumidor =  backup.idconsumidor;

commit;
```

Comment: Não deu certo , deu erro , comando SQL não encerrado adequadamente.

Comment: Experimente tirar o `uc` do `from`. Já editei a resposta.

Comment: Tirei , mas continua dando erro

Comment: @Danilo Que erro?

Comment: Cigano , o erro é : ORA:00933 : comando SQL não encerrado adequadamente

Comment: http://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/510399-atualizar-tabela/   veja se ajuda.