# Como passar dados de uma tabela para outra em php?

Tags: php, mysql

Sou novato na área de programação, e estou desenvolvendo um site de publicidade.
E estou com dificuldades, em meu a pessoa tem a opção de publicar uma propaganda dela.
Ela publica e é enviada pro banco de dados, e no painel de controle eu coloquei pra mostrar as informações da propaganda, e é nessa hora que eu preciso de ajuda.

Quando a propaganda está ok, eu queria colocar um botão: "Publicar" e iria enviar aqueles dados para outra tabela.

Como eu mostro as informações da conta no Painel:

```
<table border="1" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" height="20" bordercolor="#C0C0C0">
<tr>
<td width="50%"><h3>Descrição</h3></td>
<td width="20%"><h3>Site</h3></td>
<td width="10%"><h3>Edita</h3></td>
<td width="5%"><h3>Deleta</h3></td>
</tr>
<?php
include ("conexao.php");
$sql="select * from principal";
$res= mysql_query ($sql);
while ($dados=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
{
    echo "<tr><td>".$dados['descricaolink'];
    echo "<td>".$dados['sitelink'];
    echo "<td><a href='edita_divulgalink.php?codigo=$dados[idlink]'><img src='img/editar.png'></a>";
    echo "<td><a href='deleta_divulgalink.php?codigo=$dados[idlink]'><img width='24' height='24' src='img/deletar.png'></a></tr>";
?>
</table>
```

Antes do editar eu queria colocar um Publicar que ao clicar ele ia enviar aqueles dados que estou recebendo para outra tabela.
Alguem pode me ajudar?

Comment: possível duplicata de [Como copiar dados da coluna de uma tabela para outra tabela](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16856/como-copiar-dados-da-coluna-de-uma-tabela-para-outra-tabela)

Comment: Não me ajudou :/

Comment: Se **realmente** precisa copiar pra uma tabela separada, provavelmente é o caso de criar uma página e acessar com `publica_divulgalink.php?codigo=$dados[idlink]` usando a mesma lógica. Nesta página, você pode usar uma query do tipo [insert .. select](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html) com ID `unique` se as tabelas forem do mesmo DB, e se forem DBs diferentes, fazer um `select` no PHP, seguido de um `insert` ou `replace` com os dados coletados.

Comment: @Mateuslapa quando você diz copiar a tabela, é no navegador, ou seja, a tabela HTML ou é no banco de dados?

Answer (score -1):

Isso que você esta tentando fazer não é certo, O mais certo a se fazer é como o amigo acima falou vc criar um campo no  banco chamado publicado do tipo boolean que por padrão no seu caso ai pelo que entendi deve começar com valor false, e ao  clicar no botão publicar ser atualizado para true.

```
select * from propagandas where now() > data_inicio and now() < data_fim
```

Esse select se tiver uma  data de intervalo  de publicação

```
select * from propagandas where now() > data_inicio and now() < data_fim and publicado = true
```

ou  ainda melhor dessa forma que verifica se a publicação esta  dentro do prazo de publicação e se realmente ela esta  publicado pois ela pode ta dentro do prazo mas não esta publicada